# BigQuery - Correlated subquery over union not working

Tags: google-bigquery

When running a simple correlated subquery (below) over a union I get an error:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

If I remove the union, the query works fine. How can I get the same result without union?

```
with data as (


 select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
  union all 
  select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 

)

select
   *,
   (select count(*) from data where word = d.word) word_count_2
from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky solution based on forcing BigQuery to recompute the unioned table:

```
with data as (
 select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
  union all 
  select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 

), data_reshuffled as (
 SELECT d.*
 FROM (
   SELECT ANY_VALUE(d) d
   FROM (
     SELECT GENERATE_UUID() uuid, d
     FROM data d
   )
   GROUP BY uuid
 )
)

select
   *,
   (select count(*) from data_reshuffled where word = d.word) word_count_2
from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` d
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why does BigQuery have an issue with running the correlated subquery against the join?

Answer (score 3):

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

As the error state, you have an issue with your UNION inside the `WITH` object.

Since I don't see the logic of doing a union on a table with itself a simple solution is to remove the `UNION` like this

```
with data as (
 select * from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
)

select
   *,
   (select count(*) from data where word = d.word) word_count_2
from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` d
```

Which produce these results

[image]

Comment: I'm not really trying to run a union of a table of itself. It's just an example on public data so I can share. Please assume the join is meaningful.

Comment: Thanks Lior, a `UNION` will work if the example will be meaningful. Please do an effort to provide a real query with a problem to make it easier to help you

Comment: Union will not work regardless of the specific data. I tried this on my data before posting the question. I cannot post my original data. I think the basic question is quite clear.

Comment: This is a working SQL you can play wth `with data as (
 select 'LVII' as word, 1 as word_count, 'sonnets' as corpus, 0 as corpus_date union all
 select 'augurs' as word, 1 as word_count, 'sonnets' as corpus, 0 as corpus_date
)

select
   *,
   (select count(*) from data where word = d.word) word_count_2
from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` d
order by word_count_2 desc`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait for Google engineers to answer why the query doesn't work on real tables (non inline)